# Optimising SQL Query consisting case

Tags: sql-server

Query is taking around 3 mint to return data, how to optimise so that it can take less time?

```
SELECT A.ID, M.Name, DC.Fun_Name, CODE,
CASE 
WHEN CS.ID = 1 THEN (SELECT data FROM AAA WHERE [AAA_CODE] = CODE)
WHEN CS.ID = 2 THEN (SELECT data FROM BBB WHERE [BBB_CODE] = CODE)          
WHEN CS.ID = 3 THEN (SELECT data FROM CCC WHERE [CCC_CODE] = CODE)
WHEN CS.ID = 4 THEN (SELECT data FROM DDD WHERE [DDD_CODE] = CODE)
WHEN CS.ID = 5 THEN (SELECT data FROM EEE WHERE [EEE_CODE] = CODE)
WHEN CS.ID = 6 THEN (SELECT data FROM FFF WHERE [FFF_CODE] = CODE)      
END AS FOO,

FROM Table_A A

INNER JOIN Table_M M ON A.M_ID = M.M_ID
INNER JOIN Table_DC DC ON A.D_ID = DC.D_ID
INNER JOIN Table_CS CS ON A.CS_ID = CS.CS_ID

WHERE M.M_ID  = 'HNO3' AND A.NAME = 'Vitamin' AND CS.C_NAME = 'issue' ORDER BY M.M_ID, A.NAME
```

Comment: I hope those selects only return 0 or 1 row

Comment: Please create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with minimal query to represent the problem, include table schemas, indexes. Have you tried looking at the query plan and where the time is spent? Are proper indexes used?

Comment: @ImrePühvel  Yes, the case statement is taking time.

Comment: What about indexes? Where is query plan?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following code? The idea is to get the `[data]` for the `[foo]` column using `INNER JOINS`:

```
CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
     [ID] INT
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(32)
    ,[Fun_Name] VARCHAR(32)
    ,[CODE] VARCHAR(32)
    ,[CSID] INT
    ,[FOO] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO #DataSource([ID], [Name], [Fun_Name], [CODE], [CSID])
SELECT A.ID, M.Name, DC.Fun_Name, CODE,CS.ID
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN Table_M M
    ON A.M_ID = M.M_ID
INNER JOIN Table_DC DC 
    ON A.D_ID = DC.D_ID
INNER JOIN Table_CS CS 
    ON A.CS_ID = CS.CS_ID
WHERE M.M_ID  = 'HNO3' 
    AND A.NAME = 'Vitamin' 
    AND CS.C_NAME = 'issue';

--- updates
UPDATE #DataSource
SET [FOO] = A.[Data]
FROM #DataSource DS
INNER JOIN AAA A
    ON DS.[CODE] = A.[AAA_CODE]
WHERE DS.[CSID] = 1;

.....


UPDATE #DataSource
SET [FOO] = F.[Data]
FROM #DataSource DS
INNER JOIN FFF F
    ON DS.[CODE] = A.[FFF_CODE]
WHERE DS.[CSID] = 6;

SELECT [ID], [Name], [Fun_Name], [CODE], [FOO]
FROM #DataSource;

DROP TABLE #DataSource;
```

Comment: A.ID, M.Name, DC.Fun_Name belongs to the different tables

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma What's the issue? We are getting these values from your initial query. Only the `foo` is calculated later.

Comment: In a single query, i want to fetch all the rows with foo data as the condition specified.

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma Could you format and test the script as I posted it. Sometimes, it's not better to calculated all the stuff in a single statement. Or your code is part of function and you are not allowed to use temporary tables?

Comment: **WHERE DS.[CSID] = 1**? this is actually dynamic in my query

Comment: Do you mean you are building dynamic T-SQL statement?

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma If you want a single query then you already have that.  Good luck.

Comment: @Paparazzi I have but the case statement is consuming the time.

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma No kidding.

Comment: @AkashVishwakarma If you are building dynamic T-SQL statement which is latter executing using `sp_executesql`, I am sure we can build the above way as well. Could you test it for now, in order to be sure it can improve the performance?

Comment: Yes let me convert my code into a procedure, I'm trying @gotqn thanks